# Erlang function name getting changed at runtime

Tags: erlang, erlang-shell

I have an erlang OTP application running under release 20.
In one of the module which is a gen_statem I have below code snippet:

```
state_bitfield(internal, bitfield, #state{} = State) ->
  maybe_send_bitfield(State),
  {next_state, state_operate, State}.

maybe_send_bitfield(#state{pieces_info = PiecesInfo} = State) ->
  lager:info("Calling have_pieces"),
  case have_pieces(PiecesInfo) of
    true -> send_bitfield(State);
    _ -> lager:info("Not sending bitfield as no pieces.")
  end.

have_pieces(PiecesInfo) ->
  length([ ok || {Status, _, _} <- PiecesInfo, Status == 3 ]) > 0.
```

Additionally I use erlang.mk which defines parse transform for lager as shown below:

```
ERLC_COMPILE_OPTS= +'{parse_transform, lager_transform}' +debug_info

ERLC_OPTS += $(ERLC_COMPILE_OPTS)
```

The code compiles well but at runtime I get below error:

```
22:56:12.454 [error] Lager event handler error_logger_lager_h exited 
with reason {'EXIT',{{case_clause,['peer_fsm:4516571b-8f41-4d1b-a9cf-
bf06fc31d54e',
{internal,bitfield},some_term,error,function_clause,state_functions,
[{peer_fsm,'-have_pieces/1-lc$^0/1-0-',[{array,27,0,undefined,
{{{0,undefined,0,[],0},{0,undefined,0,[],0},
{0,undefined,0,...},...},...}}],...},...]]},...}}
```

I don't understand how the function name is getting changed/transformed to "-have_pieces/1-lc$^0/1-0-" as seen above.
Can this be because of some parse transform?
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-have_pieces/1-lc$^0/1-0-` is the name of an anonymous function inside the `have_pieces` function. You can tell from the fact that the name looks mangled.

The `-lc` in the anonymous function name stands for "list comprehension", so this anonymous function comes from that.

It's failing because `PiecesInfo` is an array (it says `{array,...` in the error), and list comprehensions require lists.

Comment: It's puzzling why is it being treated as anonymous function.

Comment: _It_ isn't. You have an anonymous function _inside_ it.

Comment: The function name contains "-lc" which indicates that it is an artefact of compiling a list comprehension.